# Searching for i686 UEFI distribution of Linux

Tags: linux, uefi, hardware-compatibility

I m trying to put a dual boot Windows 8 - Linux on a HP ENVY j069-sf (i686).

Like all HP laptop, there is a lot of proprietary drivers (even when installing Windows, I had to take 2 hour to search, download and install all of them).

So far, I tried Debian and Ubuntu, in legacy mode. Debian can install but can t boot. Ubuntu don t detect any partition and see my HDD as empty. Both needed me to download the 32bit (i386) version because AMD64 do not work.

Is there other distribution which support i686 and UEFI?

I ll add that I don t care about GUI for anything other but start Firefox/Iceweasel or VLC, the main use will be `nano` and `gcc`/`gpp`.

EDIT:

I have experience with Debian in command line (half-failed installation on old computer, couldn t install proprietary graphic-card driver, and Raspberry Pi's Raspbian), and used Ubuntu for some time.

I ve touched other distribution, but either very old version (Fedora...) or for too few times to know them (CentOS...).

Comment: have your try fedora ?

Comment: @Kiwy: Only a old version on school computer, will give it a new try.

Comment: You may have to resort to something like this: https://stomp.colorado.edu/blog/blog/2011/12/05/on-dual-booting-tpm-linux-windows-and-bitlocker/

Comment: My last encounter w/ an HP system w/ Win8 + UEFI resulted in similar frustrations as you. I found this thread last time too: http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/System-Administration/Wanted-to-install-Linux-alongside-Windows-8-UEFI/td-p/5880277#.UwNVhXVdUc0

Comment: @slm: Thanks for the links, it reference the same problem I had with Ubuntu (thought I can t find newer than 13.10 right now). I ll keep you up with my progress when I ll have the possibility to retry.